# face the performance issue in ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am facing an performance issue while using the below structure, currently i have to class

**1.Product   2.Category**

**1 product have many category

2 category have many product

1 category have many category(self)**

product Class --->

```
@Entity
@Table(name = ProductService.TABLE_NAME)
public class ProductService {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "BB_Product_Service";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_PROD_SUB_CAT = "BB_Product_Sub_category";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID = "pk_product_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME = "product_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION = "product_description";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_NOTE = "product_note";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_PRICE = "product_price";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_MAINTENANCE = "product_maintenance";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_EXPENSES = "product_expenses";
    public static final String COLUMN_STATUS = "status";
    public static final String USER_ADDED_BY_FOREIGN_KEY = "fk_added_by";
    public static final String COLUMN_USER_ADDED_ON = "added_on";
    public static final String USER_MODIFIED_BY_FOREIGN_KEY = "fk_modified_by";
    public static final String COLUMN_USER_MODIFIED_ON = "modified_on";

    public static final String TABLE_PRODUCT_CATEGORY = "BB_Product_category";


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID)
    private int productId;

    @Column(name = COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)", nullable = false)
    private String productName;

    @Column(name = COLUMN_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(500)", nullable = true)
    private String productDescription;

    @Column(name = COLUMN_PRODUCT_NOTE, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)", nullable = true)
    private String productNote;

    @Column(name = COLUMN_PRODUCT_PRICE, columnDefinition = "INT(10)", nullable = true)
    private int productPrice;

    @Column(name = COLUMN_PRODUCT_MAINTENANCE, columnDefinition = "INT(10)", nullable = true)
    private int productMaintenance;

    @Column(name = COLUMN_STATUS, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1", nullable = false)
    private int status;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = COLUMN_USER_ADDED_ON, columnDefinition = "DATETIME", nullable = false)
    private Date userAddedOn;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = COLUMN_USER_MODIFIED_ON, columnDefinition = "DATETIME", nullable = true)
    private Date userModifiedOn;


    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = TABLE_PRODUCT_CATEGORY, joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = Category.COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID))
    @Where(clause="status=1")
    private List<Category> categories;

       //Setter an Getter
```

}

Category Class---->

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Category.TABLE_NAME, indexes = { @Index(columnList = Category.COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID, unique = true) })
public class Category {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "BB_Category";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID = "pk_category_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME = "category_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_FOREIGN_KEY = "fk_parent_category_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_MAIN_PARENT_CATEGORY_ID = "main_parent_category_id";
    public static final String USER_ADDED_BY_FOREIGN_KEY = "fk_added_by";
    public static final String COLUMN_ADDED_ON = "added_on";
    public static final String USER_MODIFIED_BY_FOREIGN_KEY = "fk_modified_by";
    public static final String COLUMN_MODIFIED_ON = "modified_on";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_STATUS = "status";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID)
    private int categoryId;

    @Column(name = COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)", nullable = false)
    private String categoryName;

    @Column(name = COLUMN_MAIN_PARENT_CATEGORY_ID, columnDefinition = "INT(10)", nullable = true)
    private Integer mainCategoryId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_CATEGORY_FOREIGN_KEY, nullable = true)
    @Where(clause="status=1")
    private List<Category> categories;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = COLUMN_ADDED_ON, columnDefinition = "DATETIME", nullable = false)
    private Date createdDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = COLUMN_MODIFIED_ON, columnDefinition = "DATETIME", nullable = true)
    private Date updatedDate;

    @Column(name = USER_MODIFIED_BY_FOREIGN_KEY, nullable = true)
    private int updatedBy;

    @Column(name = USER_ADDED_BY_FOREIGN_KEY, nullable = true)
    private int createdBy;

    @Column(name = COLUMN_CATEGORY_STATUS, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1", nullable = false)
    private int status;



//Setter and Getter

}
```

From above structure everything is working fine but still get an performance issue , how can I increase the performance can i put manyTomany annotation in category entity ? please help me .....Thank in advance

Comment: We can't help you make your code faster without knowing what your code is. What is the code causing a performance issue?

Comment: @JBNizet i alredy posted my entity classes , i want to maintain the relationship in two entity , i posted how can i maintain it just want to know is there any other approach to achieve this ??

Comment: The entity classes only describe your data model. For performance it is important to know what you are doing with those entities: do you query lists of these entities or retrieve only single entities from the database? Another important point is how do you make your queries: do you use HQL or Criteria?

Comment: For performance, the queries and the database indexes and constrains are the first place to look. So, check your database for missing foreign key constraints and indexes. 
I also notice, you are using CascadeType.All. That can have impact too, because after every database update, hibernate refreshes the entity and all related entities which are already in memory. For a product, that could be all it's categories and their subcategories. If a lot of categories exist and are in memory or if database indexes are missing, that might have also an important impact.